# Kinect SDK / skeleton tracker for single arm and top view perspective?

Tags: sdk, kinect, angle, perspective

I want to track a single arm (left or right) while sitting and I'm especially interested into the shoulder and elbow joint angle in the transverse plane.
The standard setup for the Kinect seems to be a view from the front [1], but this causes problems when the arm is pointing directly into the camera. At least under the MS SDK 1.5. 
So I have experimented with an elevated (ca. 2m), down looking perspective. Unfortunately, below maybe -45 deg, the MS SDK skeleton tracker does not recognize the subject any more.

Are other SDK's like OpenNI better suited for such a situation? I wouldn't want to write my own skeleton tracker.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973071.aspx